# Angular http post request not sending any data. No body even in chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can not understand this.  This is a commonplace thing for me every day and I have no idea why this would fail like this.  It's going to be something stupid, but it's not the usual "there's no data on the server side".  There is absolutely nothing sent to the server but the post request, no body.

```
$http.post(urls.base_signup, ({
    email: $scope.email,
    google_id: $scope.google_id,
    google_token: $scope.google_token,
    name: $scope.name
}))
```

Here's the request in the Networking tab in the chrome debugger:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:paypertrade.com
Origin:https://paypertrade.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
```

Why is there no payload??

Comment: What happens if you remove the parenthesis from the data object? ``` $http.post(url, { my: data, .. }); ```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a security issue with my local server, hosts file, https and nginx setup.  Needed to add these headers in my nginx config to get this working properly:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type,Accept';
```

This is a very specific problem to my own situation, but I thought I'd share it in the off-chance that someone else starts to go insane over it.

http://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 0):

why you put data in (), try:

```
$http.post(urls.base_signup, {
  email: $scope.email,
  google_id: $scope.google_id,
  google_token: $scope.google_token,
  name: $scope.name})
```

Comment: Didn't have that to begin with.  That was just added when I was going mad over the console having syntax errors in not considering the { ... } to be an object literal.  Adding the parentheses doesn't change anything about the js execution, it's just more explicit.